# can't get a math equation display the way I like in R markdown

Tags: r, markdown

I have this math equation in the Rmarkdown document

$$ r~{contrast}~ = \sqrt{t^2^ \over t^2^+7441} $$

I can't get it displayed the LaTex nice equation.  Am I missing something. I tried.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Can you show us your LaTex attempt?

Comment: Wondering if it should be `==`?

Comment: remove the trailing carat symbol?

Comment: So... how _does_ it display?

Answer (score 0):

May be:

```
$$ r~{contrast}~ = \sqrt{t^2 \over t^2+7441} $$
```

Comment: this is the end result:

Comment: We can calculate the effect size of both contrasts with the mathematical expression
r~{contrast}~ = {\sqrt{t^2 \over t^2+7441}
. It requires the degree of freedom from the test above, which is 7441 (7445-p-1, where p=3) and the t-values from respective contracts in the output above. the whole expression was centered and displayed within a rectangle.  Still does not work the way I envisioned.  I'll try the first answer posted by Mareviv.  BTW thank,

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove spaces next to the `$` inside the formula. They sometimes throw errors when combined with single `$` symbols in Rmarkdown.
Second, your LaTeX code doesn't appear to work.
As you didn't provide clues of what results are you looking for -by posting an R code equivalent as an example-, my guess is that you want something like:

```
$r~{contrast}~ = \sqrt{\left( \frac{t^2}{t^2+7441} \right)}$
```

This link can be useful:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX

Comment: Really appreciate your help.  it works with minor revision of my LaTex expression. One discrepancy I noticed is that I used a syntax from knitr cheatsheet but it did not work (subscript, with the second ~).   I guess I have to work on my LaTex expression. I learned my LaTex long time ago and have a copy of Knuth's book. Do you have any suggestion? LaTex package?  Thanks again.

Comment: `r_{contrast}` worked for me in Rmarkdown; btw you can upvote our answers if you think they've been useful. 
For any questions regarding LaTeX, you should go to: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/](http://tex.stackexchange.com/)